# Can a variable be both a member variable and an instance variable?

Tags: vb.net

Requesting help with the following question:

My question is that in the below code, are the variables "mute" and "change" instance variables or member variables or they qualify as both, i.e. they are both member & instance variables?

Also, the variables "m" & "c" are instance variables. In addition to being instance variables are they also local variables?

```
Structure Mutable
    Private x As Integer 'x is a field/member variable
    Sub New(ByVal a As Integer)
        x = a
    End Sub
End Structure

Class ChangeValue
    Private x As Integer 'x is a field/member variable
    Sub New(ByVal a As Integer)
        x = a
    End Sub
End Class

Module Module1
    'Are "mute" & "change" member variables/instance variables or both?
    Dim mute As Mutable = New Mutable(50)
    Dim change As ChangeValue = New ChangeValue(60)
    Sub Main()
        'm and c are instance variables. They are definitely not member variables
        Dim m As New Mutable(100)
        Dim c As New ChangeValue(200)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Can you write `Dim m1 = New Module1()`? Did you write the comment on `Main()`: *m and c are instance variables...*, or it was already there? You can keep the *...They are definitely not member variables* part.

Comment: @jimi yes I wrote the comments. Are you suggesting I delete it? Will that make the question more clear?  And I did not understand `Dim m1 = New Module1()`.  I guess we cant write that as Module1 is not a data type (that the error that i got when I tried writing it)

Comment: So, there's no Instance of Module1... Are `m` and `c` Instance variables? Or Local variables? Where these non-members *live*?

Comment: Isnt that precisely the second question that I asked?

Comment: New elements have being added in the meanwhile. `m` and `c` would be Instance variables of which Instance? Can a Local Variable be an Instance Variable? Did you clarify whether there's an Instance of something here?

Comment: This smells like homework so maybe you should actually read your class notes and/or text book to learn what you've been taught.

Comment: @jmcilhinney no i can assure you its not homework. Its just that I am learning this language through self study and therefore approach experts on forums like stack overflow, sometimes even for basic topics

Comment: @jimi "c" would be the instance variable for the instance of the changeValue class being created suing New ChangeValue(). "c" would be storing the reference to that object. LIkewise "m" would represent an instance of the structure Mutable, although it wont store any reference (with Mutable being of value type). Thats what is my understanding.. As for the second question u asked: " Can a Local Variable be an Instance Variable" - I dont have clarity of thought on this , hence posted the question.

Comment: So, `m` and `c` are Local Variables that store a reference instead of a *direct* value. But neither `m` or `c` are part of the `ChangeValue` class Instance. `Private x As Integer` is. -- Don't confuse the value a variable stores with its role.

Comment: @jimi My understanding: Only "x" is an instance variable in both cases(i.e. for the structure & class) as "x" is a part of every instance being created (be it of the class or the structure). And "m" & "c" are local variables that store reference to the instance being created. "m" and "c" are not a part of the instances being created and therefore cannot be instance variables. In short, instance variables are those that an instance (of a class/structure) can access? So "x" is both a member variable (defined at module level) and it is an instance variable? Pls tell if I understand correctly?

Comment: The scope of `m` and `c` is local to the Main method, that's what defines their role before anything else. The rest is correct -- There are other instance members: see, e.g., [Instance Constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#instance-constructors)

Comment: @jimi thank you for clearing the confusion. Please clarify one last point. Going by the above discussion, the variables "mute" & "change" are member variables as they are defined at module level. They cannot be thought of as instance variable as they are not a part of an instance - they are only storing the reference to it. I believe this understanding is right? I know this request for clarification may sound redundant but still asking just to be 100% sure.

Comment: As mentioned before, it doesn't matter what `mute` and `change` *store*, what matters is the scope in which these members are declared, their access modifier, the Type they're part of and what elements this Type can define. A `Module` cannot create Instances (except the unique instance that is create when the application is run, along with a copy of its members' data) and doesn't actually define a Type or be inherited, so no Instance members (in the Object *sense*) are defined in a Module.

Comment: @Jimi many thanks. I understand that it makes no sense when I write what these variables store. Thanks again for helping me clear a lingering doubt

Comment: A `Module` is effectively a singleton.  `Public` variables of the module are hoisted into the global namespace and function as global variables.  `Private` variables of the module don't really have a common description, I don't think, because most of the vocabulary people use around "member" and "instance" relate to multiple-instance classes.  If you forced me to pick something, I'd probably call them members of the module.